# React Redux Router - Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Hi i'm using Create React App and React Redux Router.

I'm wondering if a problem i'm seeing is not really a problem. While i'm still in development i haven't pointed my domain at my new Heroku app. So the way i'm previewing my build 'online' is via the dyno name ........

https://pauliescanlon-io.herokuapp.com/

My React app seems to work fine, all routes work etc but if i hit refresh on any route other than home page, eg....

https://pauliescanlon-io.herokuapp.com/work

i get an nginx 404 error from Heroku...

I'm wondering if this is just because when previewing on Heroku the url has a "." in it and when i link up my domain this won't be an actual problem?

I'm using the "next" version of React Router Redux.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux

I can post my store.js and index.js if it'll help?

but... does anyone know if this is actually a problem or is it just because of the temporary way i'm seeing my build on the above URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem likely the custom routes need allowing via a .htaccess file, add one in the public directory:

`RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried this but it fails to push to Heroku with htaccess file add. Curiously. The refresh problem only appears when doing a hard refresh in Chrome. Normal refresh now seems to work ??